# Custom wait for selenium for angular7 application

Tags: java, selenium, angular7

We are automating an Angular 7 application using Selenium Webdriver. I need the custom waits using Javascript or JQuery that will wait for the page to render and wait for the $http response to get completed.

I've tried explicit waits but they are not working since the elements get loaded on the page but still loads and tried ng Webdriver but that is also failing.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for an element to load, indicating when the page is fully loaded? IE: If you need to interact with a button, try wait for that button.

Comment: Actually I've tried it the issue with angular applications is that the page gets loaded but still it shows the loading sign till it receives the appropriate response

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the loading spinner to not be visible?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for while the page receives appropriate response (may be $https calls ) the page get's loaded but I'm not sure how to check that using the java and selenium. Hence looking the appropriate solutions for that for angular 5 and angular 7 applications. I've tried ngwebdriver but its not working since it is not compatible above angular 2 and we have custom framework created with us and protractor is not a feasible option since we don't have appropriate time to upskill team to javascript protractor.

Answer (score 2):

These may be helpful for you. Before accessing any element check whether Jquery/Angular is done or not.

```
  public static boolean isJQueryDone() {
            Object jsResponse = tryJavascript("return jQuery.active;");
            if (jsResponse instanceof Long) {
                return ((Long) jsResponse) == 0;
            } else if (jsResponse instanceof String) {
                String response = (String) jsResponse;
                return (response.startsWith("{\"hCode\"") || response.isEmpty());
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public static boolean isAngularDone() {
            Object jsResponse = tryJavascript("return window.getAllAngularTestabilities().filter(x=>!x.isStable()).length;");
            if (jsResponse instanceof Long) {
                return ((Long) jsResponse) == 0;
            } else if (jsResponse instanceof String) {
                String response = (String) jsResponse;
                return response.isEmpty();
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        public static synchronized Object tryJavascript(String script, Object... args) {
            try {
                return execJavascript(script, args);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: execJavascript(script, args); is giving error what can I use to execute the scripts

Comment: If your application has JQuery/Angular functions then use isJQueryDone()/isAngularDone() methods to verify whether the JQuery/Angular function is done or not. JQueryDone()/isAngularDone() methods internally calls tryJavascript() method no need to provide any script/args because a static values is already given to it. Build a method to check whether the JQuery/Angular is Done or not, once it is done then click on your required field.